# what does "I feel you" mean?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

What is the meaning of this sentence. Is it just like "I understand you", or like "I agree with you".  Does it implies only that you´re getting what the other person says or that you feel the same way?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you please [edit] the context of that sentence into your question, and, if possible, add a link to wherever you found the original? If it has to do with medical rehabilitation, it may well be literal. Otherwise, it's likely to be an expression of empathy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only missing context could (possibly) redeem this sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It's a slang and informal to some American english speakers, it means: `"I understand you"`, `"I agree with you"`, `"I sympathize"`, `"I hear you"`, it denotes that you understand what they're saying and more importantly you understand how they're feeling.

checkout: [I feel you in a conversation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81023/saying-i-feel-you-in-a-conversation)

Comment: Thaks for your answer; but it´s a little confusing because for me " I understand you " not necessarily means " I agree with you". There is any difference?

Comment: yes, both phrases have different meanings. but depending on the context, 'i feel you' can be used in place of both phrases.

Comment: You could say the same about "I know what you mean", which is usually taken to imply agreement, even though that's not its literal meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It basically means "I understand you", but it's slightly more nuanced than the literal sense of "I understand you".

> A : It hurts me when people assume I'm a criminal.
>   B : I feel you.

B isn't just communicating that he **understands** A (i.e. he understands the message that is being conveyed), but that he has personal experience with **the feeling itself** (e.g. he has thought/felt the same thing himself, or maybe he can relate it to something a close friend or relative experienced)

Therefore, I think the best translation would be:

> A : It hurts me when people assume I'm a criminal.
>   B : **I know the feeling**.

Comment: I completely agree with your interpretation, but as to the best translation I'd suggest "I empathise".

Comment: @AndyT I was focusing more on a self-explanatory answer, but I agree that yours is equally valid :)